# Conductive hydrophobic material

Tags: surface-chemistry, conductivity

I was looking for a conductive hydrophobic material if there is one? If not why? I was researching and I found some material about laser etching on metals that causes superhydrophobicity but that I don't think will work if I wanted a curved surface since its roughness would be smoothed out I think. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

[image]

Comment: How about [electrically conductive polymers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conductive_polymer)?

Comment: What's the point? Typically people would just take some conductive material and cover it with some hydrophobic material.

Comment: @IvanNeretin "_Science isn't about why. It's about why not_".

Comment: @airhuff thanks that works great! Sorry forgot to reply.

Comment: @IvanNeretin I needed the outside of the material to be conductive as well